# How to compare two arrays and return the difference? (Working both ways?)

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I'm looking to achieve this in vanilla, ES6 JS. Please no jQuery! (Lodash is acceptable!)

Basically I have 2 arrays, 1 that contains objects, and 1 that contains ids.

```
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
];

const newIds = [1, 2, 3];
```

My current solution to this problem is as shown;

`const difference = newIds.filter(n => !old.some(o => o.id === n));`

This results in the return `[3]`.

Basically I'm currently using this to determine if something is missing, and create it in my database if it is missing.

However, I need to then do the opposite. If something is removed, I need to compare and remove the item.

The problem with this is; This current solution only works "1 way" so I'm unable to do what I stated above.

Ideally I only want 1 statement whether it's creation or deletion, and I only want it to return the id's of stuff that is missing from either array.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Since you wrote *"Lodash is acceptable"*, add the [tag:lodash] tag in your question: that way, the question will show up for users following (or "watching") that tag.

Comment: if you don't want to build complex logic you can easily find the difference of array using lodash js library

Comment: @SanjaysinhZala Perhaps an example? I tried use Lodash difference method but wasn't working how I wanted it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the values that appear in one but not the other use lodash's

```
_.xor(array1, array2);
```

In your case:

```
> const _ = require('lodash');

> const old = [
...   { id: 1, name: 'object_1' },
...   { id: 2, name: 'object_2' },
...   { id: 3, name: 'object_3' },
...   { id: 4, name: 'object_4' },
... ];

> const newIds = [1, 3, 5, 7];

> _.xor(old.map(x => x.id), newIds)
[ 2, 4, 5, 7 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do the same in vanilla es6 by using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Here, I have mapped the old array to only an array of ids by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then using the filter and includes on both the arrays I have found out the symmetric difference between them.

```js
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
];
const newIds = [2, 3];
const oldIds =  old.map(({id}) => id);

console.log(getDifference(oldIds, newIds));

function getDifference(oldIds, newIds){
  const diff = [...oldIds.filter(id => !newIds.includes(id)), ...newIds.filter(id => !oldIds.includes(id))];
  return diff;
}
```

We can do it another way using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Just reduce over both the arrays and return the elements which are not repeated more than once will give us the symmetric difference of the two arrays.

```js
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
];
const newIds = [2, 3];
const oldIds =  old.map(({id}) => id);

console.log(getDifference(oldIds, newIds));

function getDifference(oldIds, newIds){
  return [...oldIds, ...newIds].reduce((acc, ele) => {
  if(!acc.includes(ele)){
     acc.push(ele);
  }else{
    acc.splice(acc.findIndex(e=> ele === e), 1);
  }
  return acc;
  },[]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xor` function from lodash to get this.
Before that, you can collect all the ids from the `old`array and use that ids array for `xor`.

Check this out.

```js
const { xor } = _;
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'object_4',
  },
];

const newIds = [1, 2, 3];
const oldIds = old.map(o => o.id)
const diff = xor(newIds, oldIds);
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I know this not excatly what you want, but this can be one work around.

```js
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
];

const newIds = [1, 2, 3];

var x1 = old.filter(x => !newIds.includes(x.id)).map(z => z.id)
             .concat(newIds.filter(x => !old.some(y => y.id === x)));
console.log(x1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using ES6:

```js
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
];

const newIds = [1, 2, 3];
const oldIds = old.map(o => o.id)

const difference = [...newIds.filter(id => oldIds.indexOf(id) === -1), ...oldIds.filter(id => newIds.indexOf(id) === -1)]

console.log(difference)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_.get` with a default value as an iteratee for `_.differenceBy` so that either the array of objects or the array of numbers could be on the left hand side.

```js
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'object_1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'object_2',
  },
];

const newIds = [1, 2, 3];

const diff = (a,b) => _.differenceBy(a, b, v => _.get(v, 'id', v))
console.log({ remove: diff(old, newIds), add: diff(newIds, old) })

const otherNewIds = [1];
console.log({ remove: diff(old, otherNewIds), add: diff(otherNewIds, old) })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will find the difference using lodash:

```
const difference = _.difference(newIds, _.map(old, 'id'));
```